# lapply function to create many plots in Ggplot

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, lapply

I'm trying to plot the line graph for X=date Y=column which is XS1-XS10.
I use the lapply with a next function

```
plot_data_column = function (column) {
    ggplot(data= excess_return, aes(y=column,x=date)) +
        geom_line()+
        geom_hline(yintercept = mean(excess_return$column), color="red")+
        ggtitle(column)+
        theme_minimal()
}
```

and then use lapply to plug in the columns of the dataset into the ggplot.

```
ggplots = lapply(excess_return[,1:10], plot_data_column)
```

My problem occurs with geom_hline which doesn't recognize the column and ggtitle(column).
P.s I have tried also like this

```
ggplots = lapply(colnames(excess_return[,1:10]), plot_data_column)
```

I wonder why R doesn't accept the XS1 as it were written manually by me?
because this code perfectly works.

```
ggplot(data= excess_return, aes(y=XS1,x=date)) +
        geom_line()+
        geom_hline(yintercept = mean(excess_return$XS1), color="red")+
        theme_minimal()
```

The only thing what i want to is to iterate the XS1 to XS10.

[image]

Thank you for support

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your `excess_return` data? It'd be easier to help you out.

Comment: I have added on the question description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can adapt this to your data strucutre:

```
plot_data_column = function (.data, .column) {
  ggplot2::ggplot(data= .data, ggplot2::aes(y=!!dplyr::sym(.column),x = Petal.Width)) +
    ggplot2::geom_line() +
    ggplot2::geom_hline(yintercept = .data %>% 
                          dplyr::pull(!!dplyr::sym(.column)) %>% 
                          mean(), 
                        color="red")+
    ggplot2::ggtitle(.column) +
    ggplot2::theme_minimal()
}

plots <- names(iris)[1:3] %>% 
  purrr::map(~plot_data_column(.data = iris, .column = .x))
```

You need to change the `names(iris)[1:3]` to your names `names(excess_return)[1:10]` and `x = Petal.Width` to `x = date`.

Comment: Thank you @Domingo ! It seems the purr is a powerfull library and needs to be learnt.

Comment: A good starting point would be https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#the-map-functions, there you also have all the different loops and https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html for the symbols as parameters

Comment: I Appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
library(tidyverse)
custom_ggplot_function <- function(var, var_name) {
  
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = var)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = mean(var), color = "red") +
    labs(y = var_name) +
    ggtitle(var_name) +
    theme_minimal()
}
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>% 
  map2(.y = names(.), ~ custom_ggplot_function(.x, .y))
```